# Using .json files as data in D3

Tags: javascript, html, json, svg, d3.js

I've been trying to import a .json file into a D3 code to act as data.I'm new to D3 so I'm using a tutorial book which says I must serve the data first.
I managed to start a local server using Command Prompt, and I've created a "data" folder in my Python34 file,a put the .json data in there, and it is visible at localhost:8000.
I'm using Notepad++, and the code itself looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>D3</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="d3.js"></script>
<script>
function draw(data) {"use strict";
             d3.select("body")
               .append("ul")
               .selectAll("li")
               .data(data)
               .enter()
               .append("li")
               .text(function (d) {return d.name + ": " + d.status;});}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
d3.json("http://localhost:8000/data/service_status.json", draw);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What's wrong here? Is it the code, or something else? As I said, I'm new to D3 and fairly new to programming itself, so try to explain the answer as if I was a total beginner. I will most probably (in my near future) have to create D3 codes to visualise demographic information using either .json or .csv files, so learning how to get data from a file is very inportant for me.

Comment: Do you get an error message in the console?

Comment: It would also be helpful if you could clarify what's not working. Is the data not loading correctly?

Comment: Can you add a `console.log(data);` right after `"use strict";`? It might be that your json is incorrectly formatted. If so, data will equal null. I ran your code, and I had no problems once I added in a bunch of extra quotation marks to my json file.

Comment: I used JSONLint and it said the JSON is fine. The problem is there's nothing happening at all. When I try to run it in Firefox there's just a blank page, and no error messages at all.
I added console.log(data); but nothing's changed.